# AWS API Gateway monitoring usage per Lambda and per client (public ip)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

My UI/application is using AWS API gateway functionality (with Lambdas).
I wanted to use AWS functionality in order to track different clients (public ip address) using different API gateway resources (Lambdas).

That supposed to give me a bit of insights how my application is used. The plan is to track it per user/tenant and the simplest solution would be to use public IP address (and them move to something more sophisticated).

That address is in the CloudWatch/LogGroups/{lambda function name}. Each lambda is logging all headers from the http request:

```
def handler(event, context):
    logger.info(str(event))
```

I was planning to use CloudWatch metric filers for json (example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) but i guess that will allow me to create a metric which will be numeric (based on the number of matches determined by the metric filter). So it will not allow me to achieve my goal.

My desired state would be:
Dashboard in CloudWatch which is a chart (timeseries) showing me the number of Lambda executions per client (public IP) per lambda name. OR Dashboard in CloudWatch which is just text/table showing me the number of Lambda executions grouped by Lambda name and client (public_ip) (for a desired time range)

Now: my request seems to be very basic and common. Is there any better way to achieve it ? (i do not want to use sophisticated solutions like RUM or Xray).

Thanks,

Comment: I believe you could create a CloudWatch Logs Insights query to generate the chart you are trying to achieve https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-fast-interactive-log-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed - thanks Mark B - CloudWatch log insights was the best solution.
I have built the following query:

```
fields @message 
| filter requestContext.path like /Test/
| display `headers.X-Forwarded-For`, `requestContext.path`
| stats count() as ExecutionPerIpPerLambda by `headers.X-Forwarded-For`, `requestContext.path`
```

And this generic query allows to visualize + chart lambda executions per public_ip + lambda function.
Thanks,